# Indented text with numeric label

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tags

What would be a way to write the labelled text below, tagged with 15? I'm using align all the time but by default the text inside seems to go in mathmode, which forces me to introduce many "text"s commands.

[image]

Comment: Because this is a mixture of text and math, you would always need to switch between these modes. If you use a math environment, you have to switch to text mode for the text parts. If you use the text mode, you have to switch to math mode for the math parts. But because it is mostly math with some text I would recommend to stay with `align` (and something like `cases`) and use `\text{…}` for the text parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a box for the text, I suggest `varwidth` so the horizontal size is as small as possible. I also use `enumitem` to customize the list.

Locally increasing the leading reduces the clutter.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth} % THE trick

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{14}% to get 15 like in the picture

\noindent
equivalent to the following:
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\linespread{1.4}\itshape
there exist sets $Y_0,\dots,Y_m$ such that
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\alph*),nosep,wide]
\item $Y_0,\dots,Y_m$ are a partition of $I$,
\item $Y_j\subseteq K^{\mathfrak{A}}_{\bigvee V_k \beta'_j}(f)$, for each $j\le m$,
\item and $\dashv_{\mathfrak{S}}\varPhi'[Y_0,\dots,Y_m]$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a mix of texts and maths, yes you have to use text-related macros in math environments, s.a.  `\text{}`, or switch to math mode in regular paragraphs. Just choose the one which involves less writing.

For the custom tags, you can use `\tag{custom label}`, which displays a custom label in brackets or `\trag*{}` which puts the label literally as written and will be references as such. If you are OK to load [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, you gain access to two more macros: `\newtagform{<name>}{left}{right}` to define a new format and `\usetagform{<name>}` to switch to that format--if `default` is used as `<name>`, it restores the default format. `left` and `right` are custom delimiters e.g. `[` and `]`. BTW [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) also loads [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), so you don't need to load it explicitly.

Note that `\tag{}` if it's used suppresses the numbering for the current equation. It means in your document the numbering would following: (1), (2), custom tag, custom tag, (3), etc.

Consider this example. As you can see, when two custom tags are used the numbering stops and resumes in the next regular equation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{braces}{\{}{\}}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\usetagform{braces}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
  c = d\tag{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
  c = d\tag*{[abc]}
\end{equation}

\usetagform{default}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
  e = f
\end{equation}

References: \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2}, \ref{eq:3}, \eqref{eq:4}.
\end{document}
```

Here's the screenshot

[image]